# Exception while uploading file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

I upgraded from rails 3.2 to rails 4.
Uploadind file in my form cause

```
TypeError (wrong argument type ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile (expected String))
```

But I commented all lines in controller and I still get this error! This error appears only in POST request.
Trace: https://gist.github.com/mystdeim/6049670

Comment: Cancan causes this error :( How to fix it?

Comment: Update to Rails 4 compatible cancan version?

Comment: Which version compatible? I use 1.6.10

Comment: I don't know, you have to check that. Cancan github page doesn't say a word about Rails 4 and I think I've seen a fork specially for Rails 4.

Answer (score 1):

Cancan does not yet offer rails 4 compatibility, sorry.

There are a few open issues about rails 4, eg.

- [CanCan ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError with rails 4](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/issues/835)
- [`scoped` has been removed in Rails 4 master](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/issues/897)

Furthermore, Ryan Bates is [taking a break this summer](http://railscasts.com/announcements/11).  There are other committers, but activity is *very* light.  I don't recommend using cancan in your rails 4 project yet.

Comment: Could you advise me alternatives?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not aware of any similar libraries.  You could roll your own using the lessons from cancan, like defining all your abilities in one place.